# How to get rid of "Java was recently installed" message every time I start Safari?

Tags: safari, java

Recently, every time I start Safari, I get a popup: "Java was recently installed. To improve security and save energy, Safari did not activate Java after it was installed."

I already got the message. I don't want to click "OK" on the dialog every time I start Safari. Is there a way to get rid of the dialog (without activating Java)? Or is the only way to activate Java?